# Restrict inbound traffic to an app on CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

One can use application security groups to restrict outbound traffic originating from one's app running on CloudFoundry. Details are here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/asg.html

Say that I want by app only be visible to a certain IP address -- in other words restrict inbound traffic to certain IP addresses. I guess this could be achieved using a custom route service and binding it to the route of my app. But is there a simpler way?

I guess the usual approach would be to use an API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, a route service is one possibility.  Another is to handle this in your application.  Exactly how you do that depends on the buildpack/language being used.

An example with Java, would be to use Tomcat, which is installed by the buildpack, to restrict access by IP.  You could do this with a [Remote Address Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter).  If you're using Spring Boot, you can do something similar with the embedded Tomcat it provides.

If you're using Apache HTTPD, you can use a `Require ip 10.10.10.10` to force that requirement.  Similarly, with Nginx you can use `allow 10.10.10.10;` and `deny all;`.

For other languages & frameworks, check your docs for directions on how to limit based on the incoming IP.  The only complication to consider is that on Cloud Foundry your application sits behind proxies, so the remote IP address that your application sees will not be the actual client's remote IP.  That will reside in the `x-forwarded-for` header.  In the examples above, Tomcat, Nginx & HTTPD parse this header for you, but depending on your application & framework, you may need to manually look at this header to obtain the correct IP.

The above assumes that you want IP rejection to be specific and customizable at the application level.  If you are trying to apply more broad rules across your entire foundation, it would make more sense to apply these restrictions before traffic gets to the app or even the foundation.  Perhaps you could use a firewall in front of your foundation or on the external load balancers which accept traffic for your foundation.  Obviously this all depends on the infrastructure available to you outside of your foundation.

Hope that helps!